# Golang Correctly Handle Stdout of SSH Session

Tags: go, ssh

I am writing a Go program to connect to a Cisco wireless controller to run multiple configuration commands on connected access points. I am able to connect to and send commands to the controller via Go's SSH package `golang.com/x/crypto/ssh`.

I need to **a)** only print the output of each command I send, not the controller's prompt or login prompts, and **b)** figure out how to send successive commands after a command whose output includes `--More-- or (q)uit` prompts.

Right now I have the `os.Stdout` assigned to the SSH `session.Stdout`, which is why I'm printing more than just the output of the commands I send. How would I  manually control the output of `session.Stdout`? I know the `session.Stdout` is an `io.Writer`, but I don't know how to control what it writes to `os.Stdout`. Here is my code along with its output:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
    "io"
)

func SendCommand(in io.WriteCloser, cmd string) error {
    if _, err := in.Write([]byte(cmd + "\n")); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    // Prompt for Username
    fmt.Print("Username: ")
    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    username, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Prompt for password
    fmt.Print("Password: ")
    password, err := terminal.ReadPassword(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Setup configuration for SSH client
    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        Timeout: time.Second * 5,
        User:    username,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.Password(string(password)),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    // Connect to the client
    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "host:22", config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    // Create a session
    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Setup StdinPipe to send commands
    stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer stdin.Close()

    // Route session Stdout/Stderr to system Stdout/Stderr
    session.Stdout = os.Stdout
    session.Stderr = os.Stderr

    // Start a shell
    if err := session.Shell(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Send username
    if _, err := stdin.Write([]byte(username)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Send password
    SendCommand(stdin, string(password))

    // Run configuration commands
    SendCommand(stdin, "show ap summary")
    SendCommand(stdin, "logout")
    SendCommand(stdin, "N")

    session.Wait()
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ go run main.go 
Username: username
Password: 

(Cisco Controller) 
User: username
Password:****************
(Cisco Controller) >show ap summary

Number of APs.................................... 1

Global AP User Name.............................. its-wap
Global AP Dot1x User Name........................ Not Configured

AP Name             Slots  AP Model              Ethernet MAC       Location          Country     IP Address       Clients   DSE Location  
------------------  -----  --------------------  -----------------  ----------------  ----------  ---------------  --------  --------------
csc-ap3500   2     AIR-CAP3502I-A-K9     00:00:00:00:00:00  csc-TESTLAB-ap35  US          10.10.110.10       0       [0 ,0 ,0 ]

(Cisco Controller) >logout
The system has unsaved changes.
Would you like to save them now? (y/N) N
```

My next problem comes when the output of a command has one or more `--More-- or (q)uit` prompts and I try to send a successive command. For example, here is the output of my code when running `show sysinfo` followed by `logout`:

```
$ go run main.go 
Username: username
Password: 

(Cisco Controller) 
User: username
Password:****************
(Cisco Controller) >show sysinfo

Manufacturer's Name.............................. Cisco Systems Inc.
Product Name..................................... Cisco Controller
Product Version.................................. 8.2.161.0
Bootloader Version............................... 1.0.20
Field Recovery Image Version..................... 7.6.101.1
Firmware Version................................. PIC 16.0


Build Type....................................... DATA + WPS

--More-- or (q)uit

Configured Country............................... US  - United States
Operating Environment............................ Commercial (0 to 40 C)
Internal Temp Alarm Limits....................... 0 to 65 C
Internal Temperature............................. +23 C
External Temperature............................. +28 C
Fan Status....................................... 3900 rpm
# the "l" is missing in "logout"
(Cisco Controller) >ogout

Incorrect usage.  Use the '?' or <TAB> key to list commands.

(Cisco Controller) >N

Incorrect usage.  Use the '?' or <TAB> key to list commands.
# the program hangs here
(Cisco Controller) >
```

**TL;DR** How to manually control the output of an `io.Writer` and how to correctly handle sending commands in succession?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be using [session.StdoutPipe](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.StdoutPipe) instead of setting `session.Stdout`. If returns a `io.Reader`, allowing you do read and parse the output yourself.

Comment: @Marc Thanks! That worked for excluding the Cisco prompt. Do you know how to read `session.StdoutPipe` for each sent command? I am trying to make my `SendCommand` function like so: `func SendCommand(stdin io.WriteCloser, cmd string) (output string, err error)`.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same challenge. Thanks!